# Publishing Code Coverage Results from ReportGenerator not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am having trouble getting my code coverage reports to work, or rather, to get DevOps to pass my parameters correctly. If I download the build directory (zipped in the build), the ReportGenerator reports are available, but they don't get published. So I know that part is working at least. :)

However, when the publish step runs it creates new reports and uses those instead. My Yaml file is as follows:

```
## Generate Reports
- task: Palmmedia.reportgenerator.reportgenerator-build-release-task.reportgenerator@4
  displayName: Generate Code Coverage Reports
  inputs:
    reports: '**\coverage.cobertura.xml'
    targetdir: 'results'
    reporttypes: 'HTML;HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Badges;Cobertura'
    assemblyfilters: '-*tests*'
    continueOnError: true


# Publish Code Coverage Reports
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: Publish Code Coverage Results
  inputs:
    disable.coverage.autogenerate: true
    summaryFileLocation: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\results\cobertura.xml
    reportDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\results
    codecoverageTool: cobertura
    continueOnError: true
```

However, when I run in Debug, I get the following output:

```
##[debug]disable.coverage.autogenerate=undefined
```

I have tried the following options for passing this parameter:

```
disable.coverage.autogenerate: true
disable.coverage.autogenerate: 'true'
disable.coverage.autogenerate: 1
```

None of them have successfully passed anything to the task.

Without this flag set, the task overwrites the HTML reports generated by ReportGenerator and outputs the following:

```
##[warning]Ignoring coverage report directory with Html content as we are auto-generating Html content
```

I am working based upon the information pasted by Daniel Palme (author of ReportGenerator) [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10354), as well as reading the actual code for the task [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PublishCodeCoverageResultsV1/publishcodecoverageresults.ts).

My source code is being open sourced, so if logs or more information help you provide an answer, it is all [available here](https://dev.azure.com/bigimpactsoftware/Toolkit). A build with a good log is [here](https://dev.azure.com/bigimpactsoftware/Toolkit/_build/results?buildId=89). The Yaml file is [here](https://dev.azure.com/bigimpactsoftware/Toolkit/_git/DevOpsPipelines?path=%2FBuildCore.yml&version=GBmaster), and is called from the various other repositories in the project.

Any advice on how to get around this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Well, in standard operating procedure, get annoyed, write a long post on Stack Overflow, find a nugget somewhere, and solve your own problem.

It is not a parameter, but rather an environment variable that needs to be set. Adding the following to the start of the Yaml file takes care of it.

```
variables:
  disable.coverage.autogenerate: 'true'
```

Leaving this here to save the next person stuck on this problem days of trouble shooting. :/

Comment: I had to wait for a given time before accepting my own answer, but that was the plan once I had a solution.

Comment: Thanks this helped me out the actual Coverage reports where published into Azure Devops but when clicking on the class it didn't actually show the code with the lines.

Comment: This helped a lot. Given that DevOps isn't auto-generating a valid report for my Scala project

Comment: FWIW, setting this variable also works around the problem in Classic Pipeline builds (i.e., non-YAML). Just set it on the pipeline's Variables screen.

Comment: Also, it seems like it **does** need to be set at the job level. Adding an `env:` to the step is not enough.

Answer (score 5):

The following `env` setting accomplishes the same result as the accepted answer, but scoped only to the task.

```
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testresults/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
    pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    reportDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/testresults/coveragereport'
    failIfCoverageEmpty: true
  env:
    DISABLE_COVERAGE_AUTOGENERATE: 'true'
  displayName: Publish code coverage results
```

Edit:

I found out that the `**` in the path above may cause two coverage xml files to be found, which generates a warning. Using a single asterisk may take care of it, depending on your case.